# The "review" page should show full posts by default

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

To judge the usefulness of an answer or to see if it needs to be edited it is useful to see the full answer. The excerpt normally shown in question listings is not enough for this. You can't even say if the post is correctly formatted for the excerpt, since formatting is always stripped there.

Since the whole point of the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) pages is to review posts and this can't be done soundly without seeing them in full, these pages should show the full posts by default. I know there is a "show full answer" link below each post, but having to click that for each post individually doesn't help anybody.

For example the 10k tools' [new posts by new users view](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-user-posts) shows the full text for all posts, which makes it much more useful.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same thought the first two or three times I used `/review`, but I don't really agree with it anymore. I feel like including everything would bring in a lot of clutter that is often unnecessary. Maybe I've just gotten desensitized to the existing layout.

The subset of this request that I *do* still agree with is display of links. (Granted, links aren't explicitly mentioned, but they're a part of "full posts.") Oftentimes I'll see things in `/review` that look like comment-answers eligible for "flag for attention," e.g.

> There's a great answer here, does it help you?

But when I go to the post with full context, it turns out that "here" is a link to some page containing a legitimate answer for the OP.

Comment: Probably it depends on the target of the review. If you are looking for non-answers that should be flagged, the excerpt is often enough. If you are looking posts that need editing, the excerpts are mostly useless.

Comment: @sth interesting point. When I think of `/review`, it's almost always as a list of things that might need flagging, not as an entry point for posts that need editing.