# Stack Overflow showing advertisements from GoDaddy - really?

Tags: discussion, advertising, sopa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [After the GoDaddy SOPA boycott, why is GoDaddy being advertised on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133461/after-the-godaddy-sopa-boycott-why-is-godaddy-being-advertised-on-stack-overflo)

Stack Overflow is showing advertisements from GoDaddy - with their support of SOPA, it seems more appropriate to not accept their advertising business, no?

[image: ScreenShot]

Update:

Here's the URL: http://engine.adzerk.net/redirect/0/7703/8348/8277/224c2ffaa44c491fb7ace7e82cd7f003/45/1178/12152/634602098067744910?keywords=iis7%2ciis-7.5

which redirects to

http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/managed-hosting.aspx/?isc=gdparall3

Comment: Would you mind including the links to these ads?  I personally haven't seen them so I really have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: This was brought up earlier today at [Will Stack Overflow boycott GoDaddy because of their support for SOPA?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116891/will-stackoverflow-boycott-godaddy-because-of-their-support-for-sopa); not sure if this post was inspired by that one or if it's just a coincidence.

Comment: Well, clearly we have to honour prior commercial agreements we have. I have alerted the team and we will deal with this in due course.

Comment: @waffles Do you mind posting that as answer?

Comment: thanks god I didn't open a dup, I just saw [this banner](http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/0b85657b07694d20b1356946ba9f5088.gif)

Answer (score 10):

Stack Exchange has to honor prior commercial agreements.  [waffles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles) has alerted the team and they will deal with it in due course.

Comment: Advertising for GoDaddy has increased over the past few weeks, rather than decreased - that doesn't sound like honoring prior commercial agreements.