# Padding short answers with HTML to get rid of length check

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes I have a legit answer that's less than the 30 character minimum.

Usually I add a bit of text to make it more than 30 characters, but the extra text really doesn't contribute anything useful and is just padding.

Is it abusing the system to use an HTML comment to pad?

Example:

```
A short answer<!-- padding to 30 chars -->
```

Comment: Can you give as at least one example question where you felt such a short answer would be sufficient?

Comment: `Sometimes I have a legit answer that's less than the 30 character minimum.` [citation needed]

Comment: @YannisRizos - [This one?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116891/will-stack-overflow-boycott-godaddy-because-of-their-support-for-sopa/116918#116918)

Comment: @MartinSmith Meta doesn't count, Meta is silly.

Comment: @Yannis Rizos: What? ***No.*** Meta is ***srs bznz***.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have you got an example of such an answer? Thirty characters is not a lot. I've never come across a need to have to pad with the HTML comment.

How about providing;

1. A longer description.
2. Link to documentation.
3. Link to further reading.
4. A code example.

In terms of the title of *this* question being too short, how about doing what the system advises you to do and make it more descriptive;

1. Is it bad to pad answers to 30 chars with <!-- padding -->
2. What to do if my legit answer is less than 30 chars?
3. ... etc.

I assume this question stems from your recent answer to this question; [CSS styling input [type="??"] for select lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904653/css-styling-input-type-for-select-lists/9904667#9904667)

[Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9904667/444991) was:

> select<!-- padding padding -->

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9904990/444991) was

> The `input[type="text"]` CSS selector can be broken down into;
>
> 1. `input`; find all elements that are `input` elements.
> 2. `[type="text"]`; filter those elements by those which have the `type` attribute of `text`.
>
> Because a select box is a `<select>` element rather than a `<input type="select" />`, you can just use the `select` selector as follows;
>
> ```
> select {
>     /* blah blah blah*/
> }
> ```

Comment: Yes, sometimes I'm just lazy :p Okay, great answer to my question, I shall be more detailed from now on.

Comment: &lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;

Answer (score 4):

Using Matt's first example of a longer description...

> The selector to use is `select`.

32 characters. Easy enough!

By the way, I need to find a canonical question to close that as a dupe of. That gets asked fairly often and the answer is always the same.

Answer (score 2):

[You should read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer)