# Where can I leave feedback?

Tags: discussion, meta, feedback

Yesterday I [asked a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148501/please-no-microsoft-advertisements-here-never), marked with the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag, that got overrun by a horde.

I've got no problems with that in general. But what I'm curious about is the fact that my question kept receiving down votes after it was closed and declined. This is also not really a problem for me, but it expresses and underlines the kind of unfairness I mentioned in my question.

What is that all about? Where can I leave feedback without this "you cannot say that here" attitude coming on to one? It kind of reminds me of the cartel meeting I was part of once.

The way one deals with criticism shows much about one's self-confidence. I've seen a big lack of self-confidence here, and it really surprised me. It's one thing to be focused, and another to be unfriendly.

**The downvotes now start to swap into Stack Exchange. That really underlines what I just said. It's really a shame.**

Edit II

**Someone seems to take it personal and continues to vote me down StackOverflow. I just want to clarify that I did not a single downvote, but a few upvotes during discussion.**

Thanks again to all professionals that joined the discussion. There was no intention to harm anyone personal.

Comment: Take a second and re-read your previous question: that was not a constructive approach to achieving anything. You basically just said "I don't like Microsoft, therefore you must not be in any contact with them."

Comment: Also: I don't understand *this* question: you left feedback and heard what the community thinks of it. Sounds like the system works as intended. Assuming for a second that "ban MS ads" is not a likely result, what *else* would you have expected?

Comment: Don't confuse disagreement with defensiveness or self-confidence issues. I suspect most or all of the down-votes you received were from people who have no tangible interest in StackExchange.

Comment: For what it's worth, three people did upvote it, so I guess they share your disdain for Microsoft ads.

Comment: "*The way one deals with criticism shows much about one's self-confidence.*" The irony of this statement is absolutely delicious.

Comment: You can leave feedback here, as you did. Other users can also leave feedback on your suggestion; as they did. You *can* say that stuff here, that doesn't mean you won't get downvotes indicating people don't agree with the suggestion.

Comment: There is really not anything where you can share your feedback, asfar as I know. We share only knowledge, not feedback ;)

Comment: Feedback is welcome. Rant is not. You can ask anything you want, but people have full right to object and express their opinion.

Comment: Replying specifically to "My question even got down votes when it was ... declined.": that's a reasonable behavior, _on meta sites_. If people stop expressing disagreement with feature requests after the requests are declined, it's more likely that the requests will be un-declined in the future. (On non-meta sites, downvotes can still be used to teach the system which questions are bad, but it's less important.)

Comment: Feedback is in the comments, but the comments are about the feedback to the content. Opinions are supposed to stay as such, opinions - leave them for friends, co-workers, and family.

Answer (score 18):

Firstly, what you posted was not feedback, but a rant.

Secondly, even if you had posted it in a more considered form it would have probably been down-voted and closed.

The subject matter of Stack Overflow (and by extension Stack Exchange) is technology neutral, therefore it **must** be possible to have adverts for any manufacturer, supplier or technology. Personally I think Apple products are overpriced and overhyped, but that doesn't mean that I think they shouldn't be allowed to advertise here.

Stack Exchange is built with Microsoft products and runs on Microsoft operating systems, but that doesn't stop people setting up site (four at the last count) that deal specifically with hardware and software that competes directly with Microsoft.

https://askubuntu.com/

https://unix.stackexchange.com/

https://apple.stackexchange.com/

https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: «...it must be possible to have adverts for any manufacturer, supplier or technology.» [Some exceptions apply, void where prohibited.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116891/will-stack-overflow-boycott-godaddy-because-of-their-support-for-sopa)

Answer (score 13):

Even though (I assume) most of us would still disagree with your question in a perfect form, your particular question read like nothing more than an anti-Microsoft rant. Phrased somewhat more neutrally, you would not have received as many downvotes as you did now.

That being said, keep in mind that a large part of the community works with and develops for Microsoft's tools and platforms. And we might not see eye to eye on the problems you perceived with those. What's more, as we informed you about, this very site basically runs on their products and technologies.

The partnership between Microsoft and SO/SE is also a very positive one IMO. Not just for them, but (especially with the [current competition](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/09/apptivate-ms-a-windows-8-app-development-contest/?cb=1)) for the community as a whole.

As a last point, as we have explained to you, downvotes on Meta often simply mean disagreement. And you happened to propose/ask something that a lot of people disagreed with. Nothing more, nothing less. No self-confidence issue. No mean-spirited downvotes. Nothing personal or unfriendly.

At least, that is my view on what happened. Where you can ask any future questions like that? Well, right here. But try to keep it somewhat neutral and constructive. You might perhaps want to have a read through: [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying)

Comment: Sorry guys, I just wanted to leave a feedback, not become clubmember ... Never mind. Won't happen again. Be shure.

Comment: You can leave constructive feedback whenever you want. Sometimes we agree. Sometimes we disagree. Rep on Meta SO doesn't mean a whole lot to begin with. So don't sweat the points you've lost. They wouldn't have bought you anything.

Comment: What I expected, was to get ignored. This is the way, "feedback" normally works. I've never seen a company or it's members yelling on a customer that fills the feedback form. Normally they have trained professionals to calm down customers. Don't expect the people to be so called "neutral" when feedbacking.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the nature of this Q&A. Yes, this still is a Q&A. And anything can (and often will) be actively discussed. If you would have liked to leave simple feedback, you could perhaps have mailed the team. But I would advise you to read the last link in my answer. That will really help you in future cases.

Comment: @ansi_lumen: Meta sites are not for "feedback". At least, not in the way you mean it. Meta sites are first and foremost places for the community to discuss issues about the site and community. That means that opinions about things are subject to the community. If you put forward an idea, the community will judge it. That's how it works. If you ask for Stack Overflow to ditch the Q&A thing and start becoming more like a PHP web-forum, you will be downvoted and have your question closed, because that's not a good idea.

Comment: Unforunately I got here, when I followed the feedback link in the footer of stackexchange.

Comment: Yep, and I still think it's the correct place. That the experience was not what you expected is due to your unfamiliarity with the site. Now you know.

Comment: @Bart: Indeed. Another lecture in social group studies.

Comment: @ansi_lumen - You aren't a customer of Stack Exchange. You're a user. There's a difference.