# Don't show protections on closed questions

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, protected-questions

I just noticed [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116891/will-stack-overflow-boycott-godaddy-because-of-their-support-for-sopa), the GoDaddy-SOPA one.

On thing that confused even me, as a 6k user on Meta, was this:

[image]

Now, I knew after a second's thought that the question was closed and no new answers were being accepted. However, that protection threw me off. Specifically the last line:

> To answer it, you must have earned at least **10 reputation** on this site.

So... If I have 10 rep I can answer it?

No, but that's what it says.

The whole point of a protection is to keep answers from new users clogging up the question. If the question is closed, it doesn't need the protection, right? If it is later reopened, the protection should come back.

Therefore, I propose that we simply **hide the protection indicator** when a question is closed,** to reduce a small amount of confusion.

Comment: The irony that this question was closed...

Comment: @Cole Now we need a mod to protect it.

Comment: It won't let me answer. :(

Comment: @animuson Did you really just protect this? Oh the irony.

Comment: Thanks to @animuson for liking fun :)

Comment: "`To answer it, you is have earned`" Wait, is that actually what the notice said?

Comment: The fact that this question was also flagged as duplicate and protected confused me for a second.  Oh, the irony.

Comment: @BLaZuRE Someone flagged it?